# Flutter FloatingActionButton and IconButton

Tags: flutter

How can I create a `FloatingActionButton` like in the image?

I tried using `FloatingActionButton`, but it looks like a whole button with a circle.

[image: Sample Image]

I need something like an `IconButton` as shown in the image.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need the one which is marked in the image or the blue button "View in your room"?

Comment: @dhuma1981 He wants the what is marked.

Comment: May I ask how you achieved the "View in Your Room" functionality if it does work, i.e. e.g. which plugin you used.

Answer (score 1):

[`IconButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) will actually deliver the result you are aiming for!

A [`FloatingActionButton`](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html), by guidelines, will always deliver the design you find on your "View in Your Room" titled button.

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.back),
  onPressed...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [IconButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) as below

```
// Icon Button
new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
          tooltip: 'Facorite icon',
          color: Colors.blue, //set color which you want
          onPressed: () {
             // Do your work 
          },
),
```

Comment: but how can i put a iconbutton up there without appbar?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use **actions ** property of appbar to put icons on the right side of title and **leading** property to put a leading icon.

```
appbar: new AppBar(
    leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
    actions: <Widget>[
                         new Icon(Icons.search),
                         new Icon(Icons.search),
                 ],
   title: new Text("title"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an Icon inside a GestureDetector widget. This will give you the result you want, but also getting rid of the unnecessary padding around an IconButton.

```
GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {},
                 child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black)
               )
```